# preparation of an abstract database in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a program written in php, but I need to replace the query function to have the query fub for query insert, update and delete. In addition, the query function should return the Resource class object and the function
execute the number of rows that affected the request (affected rows). I do not have 
much idea how to go about it.

```
?php
function db_connect( $error=null, $configfile='database_config.php' )
{
require_once( $configfile );
//  $conn = pg_connect( "host=$server dbname=$database user=$user password=$password" );
//  $error= pg_last_error( $conn ); 

$conn = mysqli_connect( $server, $user, $password, $database ); 
$error= mysqli_error( $conn ); 
/* change character set to utf8 */
mysqli_set_charset($conn, "utf8");
return $conn;
}

function db_query( $conn, $query, $error=null )
{
//  $res=pg_query( $conn, $query );
//  $error=pg_last_error( $conn );

$res=mysqli_query( $conn, $query );
$error=mysqli_error( $conn );
return $res;
}

function db_fetch( $result )
{
//  return pg_fetch_assoc( $result );

return mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result );
}

 function db_genid( $link, $table, $idcol )
 {
    $res=db_query( $link, "select max($idcol) from $table" );
    $row=db_fetch( $res );
    if ( $res ) return $row[0]+1;
    return 1;
 }

function db_close( $conn )
{
 //  pg_close($conn);

  mysqli_close($conn);
 }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Tworzenie tabeli</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>

<body>

Dane tej tabeli:
<table border="1">
<?php
  $link=db_connect();
  $result=db_query( $link, "select * from osoba" );
 while ( $row=db_fetch( $result ) )
 {
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach ( $row as $col ) echo "<td>$col</td>";
    echo "</tr>";   
  }
 db_close( $link );
 ?>
</table> 
<hr><h2> Zrodlo pliku </h2>
<?php 
 show_source(__FILE__);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please, don't write wrappers around `mysqli`. This usually walls off important security features like **prepared statement with placeholder values**. You want your queries to be laid bare where mistakes are obvious, not obscured by a pointless layer of abstraction.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: If you're not sure where to start, have a look at [development frameworks](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) to see what they offer. They come in a variety of styles, from really lean like [Fat-Free Framework](https://fatfreeframework.com/) to very feature complete like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/). Most include some kind of login mechanism out of the box so you won't have to write your own. They also show you how to organize your code so you don't end up with a confusing stew of PHP, HTML, CSS and SQL that is impossible to maintain or iterate on.